# How to access protected members in a multiple inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

I want to use protected member in a constructor of derived class, but I'm not able to use it. I have a class where I try to redirect the output to the standard or other stream. Here is my code.
Redirection.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Redirection {
public:
    Redirection(std::ostream &stream)
    :outStream(stream)
    {
    };
    Redirection()
    :Redirection(std::cout)
    {
    };
protected:
    std::ostream &outStream;
};
```

Derived.h

```
#include "Redirection.h"

class Derived : public Base, public Redirection
{
public:
    Derived();
    Derived(std::ostream& stream);
    ~Derived();
};
```

Derived.cpp

```
#include "Derived.h"

Derived::Derived()
         :Derived(std::cout)  
{
}
Derived::Derived(std::ostream& stream)
         :Base(),
          oustream(stream)
{
}
```

When I try to build I get the following error:

```
error: class 'Derived' does not have any field named 'outStream'
```

And if I modify like this:

```
    Derived::Derived(std::ostream& stream)
         :Base()              
{
     oustream = stream;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected
   basic_ostream& operator=(const basic_ostream&) = delete;
error: within this context: mOutStream = stream;
```

I'm getting these errors because the multiple inheritance? Or do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Hint: which one of the base classes has a constructor that takes a `std::ostream&`?

Comment: The Redirection class. The Base class only has virtual methods

Comment: Good. And what does that constructor allow you to do?

Comment: As @juanchopanza hinted, use the constructor of your `Redirection` class to forward `std::cout` in the constructor initialization list of your `Derived`class.

Comment: The constructor only sets a variable. But my code is in the Redirection.h as you can see

Comment: What about doing `Derived::Derived(std::ostream& stream) : Redirection(stream)`? This perfectly initializes `outStream`.

Comment: If you don't know how to access protected members of a base class, then you are at the stage of learning the language.  If you are at the stage of learning the language, then my advice to you would be to stay away from using multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As state in the comment, use the following:

```
Derived::Derived(std::ostream& stream) : Base(), Redirection(stream) {}
```